# How to handle overlapping dates in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, date, time, overlap

Im *attempting* to build a reservation system with items (ie Beamers), now I want to check with AJAX wheter the given item_id is available during the users given start and enddate

**edit: was a bit unclear, I want to do it with MySQL and PHP, the AJAX is just the way I request the result (available yes/no)**

How would I go with this?

My table looks 'like' this:

```
reservation_id int PK
reservation_createDate datetime
reservation_startDate datetime
reservation_endDate datetime
item_id int FK(items.item_id)
```

Let's say I have the following already 'reserved' in the DB:
(for convienience, all item_id = 1)

```
reservation_id 1, item_id 1, from 2011-7-10 till 2011-7-14
reservation_id 2, item_id 1, from 2011-7-14 till 2011-7-16
reservation_id 3, item_id 1, from 2011-7-16 till 2011-7-20
```

And the user wants to reserve item_id 1 from 2011-7-12 till 2011-7-18, which as you can see wont go due to all 3 reservations being in the way for that..
How would I do this with MySQL ?

Comment: are you using an actual date field in your sql table?

Comment: With AJAX (meaning: JS), with PHP (see tag), or with MySQL: Which of these you are wanting to use now? :?

Comment: edited post above, I do want it with PHP/MySQL, and yes I use datetime fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)<1 AS Available FROM `TABLE` WHERE (`startDate`>CHECKING_START_TIME AND `startDate`<CHECKING_END_TIME) OR (`endDate`>CHECKING_START_TIME AND `endDate`<CHECKING_END_TIME) OR (`startDate`<CHECKING_START_TIME AND `endDate`>CHECKING_END_TIME)
```

If the result is greater than 0, then there is an overlap

Comment: That's partly true, tho in your answer, if I enter 2011-7-11 till 2011-7-12 gives me 0 results, while there is a reservation for 10 till 14 in the DB..

Comment: @Sander, DOH! haha I added one more condition to address that case

Comment: Okay! I think we got all possibilities now :D